# Solving a Laplacian with boundary conditions at infinity

Tags: differential-equations, boundary-condition-at-infinity

I'm trying to solve a Laplacian given the following boundary conditions:

\begin{align*}
V(x,y,0) &= 0\\
V(x,y, z \to \infty) &= 0\\
V(x,y, z = \sqrt{a^2-x^2-y^2}) &= 0
\end{align*}

Essentially, the region I'm considering is an infinite plane of conducting material with a hemisphere at the center.

I tried using this to solve it:

[image]

I think the clear problem is my usage of infinity here, but I don't know how else to work around it.

Comment: You could always pick a finite, large value? You're looking for the approximate numerical solution anyway, so assuming you pick a sufficient value it's not much of an assumption.

Comment: I should actually be using DSolve, as I am indeed looking for an analytical solution. My mistake.

Comment: That might fix it, then. Not sure if `DSolve` can handle this, but maybe.

Comment: @b3m2a1 so you think an analytical solution will still work with that?

Comment: I think you are going to need $x$ and $y$ bc's also.

Comment: @BillWatts There aren't any as far as I'm aware. Is it necessary for a solution?

Comment: Probably.  I assume the solution goes to zero at x,y =+-Infinity.  Seems like a second order pde in three dimensions needs more than three conditions.

Comment: With all your bc's equal to zero, What non-zero condition makes your $V(x,y,z)$ equal to anything other than zero.